# Highcharts small size div not showing minorTickInterval

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I'm trying to add Highcharts to my page, but the problem is my DIV tag size is quite small (233px,98px) and I want to show minorTickInterval in it, but highcharts truncate them because of small DIV size.

http://jsfiddle.net/a62nhs7f/

Is there anyway to show the inner lines of the interval in the small size?

```
var options  = {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        },  
        title: {
            text: '',
            align: 'high',
            enabled: false

        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            align: 'high',
            enabled: false
        },
        /*
        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 1,
            breaks: [{
                from: 5,
                to: 10,
                breakSize: 1
            }]
        },
        */
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
         yAxis: {
            gridLineWidth:1,
            lineWidth: 1,
            min: 0,
            //tickWidth: 1,
            minTickInterval:5,
            minorGridLineWidth:1,
            minorTickInterval: 0.1,
            minorTickLength: 2,
            //type: 'logarithmic',
            minorTickInterval: 5,
            //minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            //minorTickLength: 0,
            title: {
                text: '',
                //align: 'high',
                enabled: false
            },
            labels: {
                //enabled: false,
                style: {"font-size":'8px'},
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },  
            /*gridLineColor: '#c9d5ba',
            gridLineWidth: '1',
            lineColor: '#222222',
            lineWidth: 0,*/
            categories: [1.2, 2, 3.1, 4.3, 5.1, 5.9, 6.7, 7.5, 8.3, 9.1, 9.8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<a style="color:green" data-value="' +[this.value] + '">' +
                        this.value + '</a>';
                },
                style: {"font-size":'8px'}
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [5.7, 11.1, 22.2, 38.1, 51, 66.6, 83.3, 101.1, 118.6, 135.7, 150.9, 161.4, 169.2, 172.8, 176.8, 178.5, 179.7, 179.9, 180, 179.9, 179.1]//,
            //pointInterval: 500
        }]
    };
```

Thanks

Comment: Lowest minorTickInterval that will fit in smaller chart is about 12.777 - smaller interval will not allow to create separate lines - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a62nhs7f/2/). How would you like to fit 40 lines (200 / 5 = 40) in 48 pixel height plot area?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the line markers. I think It is better solution for you.

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
},
```

Chek my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a62nhs7f/1/).

Comment: In your demo, the small chart is not showing lines, so its not working